# beginner XMLHttpRequest stuck on processing

Tags: php, http, xmlhttprequest

I am testing a script to allow my calendar to load the current month. However when I open the page it is stuck only displaying "processing..." I cannot figure out why

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function initialCalendar(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    showmonth = month;
    showyear = year;
    var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("showCalender").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

and the body is:

```
<body onLoad="initialCalendar();">

<div id="showCalendar"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: try jquery, way easier :-) it will be hard at first but worth it

Comment: Does the `onreadystatechange` ever return anything?

Comment: First places to look are the JavaScript Console for any errors and the `calendar_start.php` for any signs of that file being `POST`ed to. Do you have any logging in that PHP for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spelled Calendar with an e in your onreadystatechange call, other than that it should work.

I would recommend moving your "processing" line above your hr.send(vars) statement to avoid a race condition, as well.